# Query to get last cost

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to do this query, in sql server, but something is wrong. Need some help...

I have a table with item movements and another one with other movements (buy) where I find the cost of each item in each date when I buy it. So, I just need first table with last cost based on the date of movement finding the cost on second table on the last date.

In other words, only must search the records from the second table with date lower than the first table date for that item and return the cost of the most recent date.

Examples:

First Table

```
REF     DATE
1       2015-10-15
1       2015-08-30
2       2015-09-11
3       2015-05-22
2       2015-03-08
2       2015-07-15
3       2015-11-14
1       2015-11-20
```

Second Table (Buy)

```
REF     DATE         COST
1       2015-08-20   150
1       2015-10-12   120
2       2015-04-04   270
2       2015-06-15   280
3       2015-03-01   75
3       2015-10-17   80
```

I need this result:

```
REF     DATE        Cost
1       2015-10-15  120
1       2015-08-30  150
2       2015-09-11  280
3       2015-05-22  75
2       2015-03-08  -
2       2015-07-15  280
3       2015-11-14  80
1       2015-11-20  120
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  ft.*,
            st.[Cost],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ft.[Ref],ft.[Date] ORDER BY st.[Date] DESC) RN
     FROM   FirstTable ft
            LEFT JOIN SecondTable st ON ft.[Ref] = st.[Ref]
                                    AND ft.[Date] >= st.[Date]
)
SELECT  Ref,
        [Date],
        [Cost]
FROM    cte
WHERE   RN = 1
```

or if you dont want to use a cte.

```
SELECT
    Ref,
    [Date],
    [Cost]
FROM
    (SELECT
        ft.*,
        st.[Cost],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ft.[Ref],ft.[Date] ORDER BY st.[Date] DESC) RN
     FROM
        FirstTable ft
        LEFT JOIN SecondTable st ON ft.[Ref] = st.[Ref]
                                    AND ft.[Date] >= st.[Date]
    ) t
WHERE
    t.RN = 1
```

Comment: My first thought was to do this with a cte+ranking function. Then I read @Giorgos answer, and cried.

Comment: Yeah I threw this out there because I thought it might have a better execution plan, and perform better than `Outer Apply`. Most people never pay any attention to that though, but someone might run across this in the future and take that into account.. @Jamiec

Comment: In fact, after testing both solutions in the production database with thousands of records , no doubt that the `outer apply` is too much slower - no comparison. Thanks @JamieD77

Comment: @PJLG This is true. We had a similar situation in our production database where the outer table has million of rows. The problem with `OUTER APPLY` is that it has to be executed once for each row of the outer table. `OUTER APPLY` offers a more succinct syntax and is better suited for situations where the outer table is small sized.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT [REF], [DATE], [COST]
FROM Table1 AS t1
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 COST
  FROM Table2 AS t2
  WHERE t1.REF = t2.REF AND t1.DATE >= t2.DATE
  ORDER BY t2.DATE DESC) AS t3
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ae41e/1)

Comment: Thanks @Giorgos! It seems It's all I need.